# Only display custom field if it there is a value inside

Tags: custom-field

Quite a simple question really, but unsure how to do it. I have this little bit of code:

```
<li><span>
            <?php if ( function_exists('get_custom_field_value') ){
                    get_custom_field_value('Essential info 5', true);
            } ?>
            </span></li>
```

...and I want to find out how I can adjust it so that if that particular field is empty, it does not display the list item at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use empty function to check if the return value is empty or not:

```
   <?php if ( function_exists('get_custom_field_value') ):
        $custom_field_value = get_custom_field_value('Essential info 5', true);
        if(!empty($custom_field_value)):
        ?>
        <li><span>
           <?php echo $custom_field_value; ?>
        </span></li>
        <?php
        endif;
   endif; ?>
```

also check if the function 'get_custom_field_value' is returning with echo statement, you may need to change that to just return the result and not to echo it out.

Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: You should wrap your HTML inside of your conditional to keep the list item from displaying.