# How to use conditional statement with custom field

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

I think it is a simple thing but I am not good on php so :( 
can you guys tell me how I can use an if condition with my custom filed. Below is my current code.

```
<div class="courtesy"><?php echo post_custom('courtesy'); ?></div>
```

I want **courtesy** to show if it has a value. Right now if there is no value then a blank div is shown. I don't want a blank div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [`get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)

```
$courtesty = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'courtesy', true );
// check if the custom field has a value
if( ! empty( $courtesty ) ) {
  echo '<div class="courtesy">' . $courtesty . '</div>';
}
```

Comment: yes. thank you so much. yes i am looking for this. thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome. I have just realized that this is technically a duplicate of http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29069/only-display-custom-field-if-it-there-is-a-value-inside so next time check for similar questions.